# redirect of url to "HOME" Page

Tags: php, mysql

When i type anything beyond my url path Eg: http://example.com/doctorlist/ngffghf5235235 , I want it to get redirected to my home page i,e.. http://example.com  . How can I do it .
I have my .htacess as follow

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/(css|images|js)/
RewriteRule ^home/(.*)$ index.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^doctorlist/(.*)$ innerpage.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^appointment-list/(.*)$ detailspage.php?doc_id=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^register-plus-appointment-form/(.*)$      register_plus_appointment_form.php?doc_id=$1&time_id=$2&date=$3&time=$4 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^appointment-form/(.*)$ appoint_form.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^appointment-confirm-form/(.*)$ appointment_form.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Just in case you want to eventually link to something past your home path, but only to valid links, you might want to consider making a custom 404 page that will redirect to your home page. There's an easy to follow guide here http://www.thesitewizard.com/archive/custom404.shtml

Answer (score 1):

to redirect every request to a certain page, eg index.php

```
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php [L]
```

hope this helps

Comment: This gives an internal server error in my first page i.e. HOME page http://example.com

Answer (score 0):

According to your tags, I assume you need this for your Zend Framework application. So this will do the job :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

See : http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.application.quick-start.html

Comment: I need it in core php .